# Convert Protobuf to Avro in Java: FileDescriptor can't be cast to Descriptor

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, avro

Simply trying to get an Avro schema from a protobuf Java class with

```java
ProtobufData model = ProtobufData.get();
Schema schema = model.getSchema(MyProto);
```

the MyProto class was generated from the `.proto` file with `protoc`

but on the `getSchema` call I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor 
cannot be cast to class com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$Descriptor
```

The `org.apache.avro.protobuf.ProtobufData.getSchema` method looks like:

```java
public Schema getSchema(Class c) {
    Schema schema = schemaCache.get(c);

    if (schema == null) {                         // cache miss
      try {
        Object descriptor = c.getMethod("getDescriptor").invoke(null);
        if (c.isEnum())
          schema = getSchema((EnumDescriptor)descriptor);
        else
          schema = getSchema((Descriptor)descriptor);  // <-- fails here
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
      schemaCache.put(c, schema);                 // update cache
    }
    return schema;
  }
```

and it fails at the casting to Descriptor.

So, I'm not sure what I can do about this. I'm not sure why my protobuf object class returns a `FileDescriptor` and not a `Descriptor`.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like this Protobuf Object embeds multiple messages and picking a message type within the class helped get through this error.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and solved it . You need use the inner class of your proto class. like this com.cloud.log.proto.StaExpDetailProto$StaExpDetail

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).